# How to rename several filenames all stored in a single file

Tags: unix, filenames, edit

I have a text file containing filenames of 1300 files:

```
mmjr0_si2166.wav
mesd0_si1002.wav
mjes0_sx214.wav
mjln0_si819.wav
mkcl0_si1721.wav
.
.
.
mjth0_sx216.wav
```

how can I edit the filenames in UNIX so that instead of their names, each line shows their paths? I mean something like this:

```
/Users/Desktop/TIMIT_wav/mmjr0_si2166.wav
/Users/Desktop/TIMIT_wav/mesd0_si1002.wav
/Users/Desktop/TIMIT_wav/mjes0_sx214.wav
/Users/Desktop/TIMIT_wav/mjln0_si819.wav
/Users/Desktop/TIMIT_wav/mkcl0_si1721.wav
.
.
.
/Users/Desktop/TIMIT_wav/mjth0_sx216.wav
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -i -e 's;^;/Users/Desktop/TIMIT_wav/;' file_with_filenames.txt`

Which will make substitution (`s/from/to/`) of the beginning of line (`^`) with desired path (`/Users/Desktop/TIMIT_wav/`).

Comment: To avoid the need for all those escapes, use an alternate separator: `sed -i -e 's;^;/Users/Desktop/TIMIT_wav/;' file_with_filenames.txt`. That makes it quite a bit more readable...